# Will the same lock ring fit 11T or 12T ring, SRAM cassette?

Tags: cassette, sram

I am currently running Sram PG1070 12-28, but would like to upgrade to 11-28. I can get 11T cog for pretty cheap, but I saw I might also have to get a different lock ring then. Is that true, or could I use the one I am currently using? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting thought.    The lockring has to fit the thread inside the freehub body, so that part must be the same size always.   However you're concerned with the outer diameter and how it could interfere with the chain on the 11T cog.   I'm guessing the lockrings will be identical, so you don't need a new one unless the old one is damaged.   But this is a guess, hence comment not answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need an 11T specific lock ring.

The outer diameter of the 11T lockring is definitely smaller, a 12T lockring won't let the chain sit properly on an 11T cog. The threaded section is the same size.